# MVCContrib grid - select row

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-2, mvccontrib

I have a MVCContrib grid that shows selected properties from an Account object.  I want the user to select a row and be taken to another page to view the full properties of the object represented by the row they clicked.  How do I add a .Selected action to the rows of the grid?

Answer (score 4):

I just came across a similar problem today.

You can use the .RowAttributes Like so:

```
Html.Grid(Model).Columns(column => 
{
    column.For(e => e.Id); 
    column.For(e => e.Message); 
})
.RowAttributes(x => new Dictionary<string, object>
    {{"onClick", "window.location.href = 'google.com'"}})
.Render();
```

In result, when you click on a  it will trigger the javascript "onclick" and open up google. You can change the url to pass in an Id by using the "x" in the Lamda.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using the Grid in an MVC3 context, you can also accomplish this via an extensions class on the server side:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using MvcContrib;
using MySolution.ViewModels;

namespace MySolution.Models.Extensions
{
public static class RowAttributeExtensions
{
    public static Hash GetRowAttributes(this MySolution.ViewModels.Model)
    {

        string onclickFunctionBody = "{window.location.href = '/MyController/MyAction?id=" + Model.Id + "'; return false;}";
        Hash hash = new Hash(onclick => onclickFunctionBody)
        return hash;
    }
}
}
```

and on the client side this will take the form of:

```
@Html.Grid(Model).RowAttributes(row => row.Item.GetRowAttributes()).Columns(column =>
{
    column.For(c => c.Col1);
    column.For(c => c.Col2);
    ...
})
```